# Retrieve API Names of all components from salesforce

Tags: api, metadata-api, tooling-api, label

I want to retrieve API names of all the components from Salesforce Org. I used Force.com Migration tool(ANT) to retrieve Component names but I am getting the label of all the components.

For Ex.  ComponentType = ApexClass

Label = Apex Object Name

Expected outcome
         API Name =   Apex_Object_Name__C

Is there any way other than Migration tool such as Tooling API?

Thank You.

Regards,
Amit Patil

Comment: Apex Classes don't have the `__c` suffix. That is only for custom objects and fields. The Tooling API does expose [ApexClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexclass.htm).  If you SOQL the `NamespacePrefix` and `Name` from there you will have the details you need.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thanks for the reply. Apex Class is just an example, but I want to retrieve all the components with API names such as PageLayout, CustomObject, ListView, VisualforcePage etc.